# HTML Forms with drop down items, how to remove it from in realtime for the next form?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `JSP` page that is populating 3 different drop down menus.

They are all populated the same. I am looking for a `javascript` way that in realtime if they choose one from the dropdown the next one they go to the dropdown list won't have that option in it.

Comment: That's actually a variation on a pretty common problem. I would advise you to search more.

Comment: Can you explain more your problem and maybe give some clue of your current research on the subject ?

Comment: So it is a bunch of different questions , then an input for an answer.  But if they choose one and answer it, I want to remove it in real time for the next drop down menu.  The list is being created in the java back end . There are 3 drop down menus on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have 3 selects "Select1","Select2",and "Select3".  Add onchange event to "Select1":

```
<script language="javascript">
function Select1_OnChange() {
    var elemSelect1 = document.getElementById("Select1");
    var elemSelect2 = document.getElementById("Select2");
    var elemSelect3 = document.getElementById("Select3");
    var selValue = elemSelect1.options[elemSelect1.selectedIndex].value;
    elemSelect2.remove(getIndexFromValue(elemSelect2,selValue));
    elemSelect3.remove(getIndexFromValue(elemSelect3, selValue));
}
function Select2_OnChange() {
    var elemSelect2 = document.getElementById("Select2");
    var elemSelect3 = document.getElementById("Select3");
    var selValue = elemSelect2.options[elemSelect2.selectedIndex].value;
    elemSelect3.remove(getIndexFromValue(elemSelect3, selValue));
}
function getIndexFromValue(objSelect,strValue) {
    var ret;
    for (i = 0; i < objSelect.options.length; i++) {
        if (objSelect.options[i].value == strValue) {
            ret = i;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
</script>
```

Tags might look like:

```
<select id="Select1" name="Select1" size="1" onchange="Select1_OnChange()>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>
<select id="Select2" name="Select2" size="1" onchange="Select2_OnChange()>
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>
<select id="Select3" name="Select3" size="1">
    <option value="red">Red</option>
    <option value="green">Green</option>
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks! And then how would I add that to my html page?

Comment: Add <script language="javascript"></script> somewhere in your HEAD tag.  Place the code I posted inbetween the <script> and the </script>.  Add onchange events to select tags: <select id="Select1" name="Select1" size="1" onchange="Select1_OnChange()"> and <select id="Select2" name="Select2" size="1" onchange="Select2_OnChange()">

Comment: what if it has <option value=

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  You obviously will have <option> tags inbetween all your selects. Can you be more clear?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I added it in as you said but it is not removing the elements for some reason.

Comment: I edited my answer to be more clear.  Are you still having issues?

Comment: I think they problem is that I am getting the option values generated from a java backend in a for loop, so I don't know what they are to put a value to, if that makes sense

Comment: That one works much better! It works on the first and second one, then problems between 2 and third.  Also, is there anyway if they go back and switch that it re populates it?  Thanks for all the help, I truly appreciate it.